# How to convert a Future in flutter to a Stream

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a function that returns a Future of the type duration.

```
Future loadur(TimerService timerservice) async {
 var dur = Duration.zero;
 dur = await timerservice.currentDuration();
 return dur;}
```

The future takes duration from a timerservice which updates itself to run a timer.Now i want the future to be converted to a stream so i can show it in a StreamBuilder(Futurebuilder doesn't update the timer).

Any way to convert the future to a stream of duration will be helpful.

Comment: Can't make any sense of the question. Can you please explain what the actual problem is you try to solve?

Comment: I have a timerservice which contains a timer/stopwatch,the above function returns the time from the timerservice as a future.As it is a timer it updates every second or so.Now i want to display the duration which i can using a futurebuilder but it wont update every second.So i need to use a stream builder,but the duration is a future

Comment: Future has .asStream() Method to Convert to Stream.

Comment: A Future converted to a stream would still only emit a single event. Perhaps you want to use the duration to create a `Stream.periodic(duration)`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Here is a scenario  `connectivity` plugin has a Future to get `WIFIBSSID` whenever user switch   to new wifi AP getting BSSDID ?

Comment: @Bawantha I guess something like `Connectivity().onConnectivityChange.asyncMap((_) => Connectivity().getWifiName()).listen(...)`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

you can Use `Stream.fromFuture(dur)`