# How to connect future result with stream in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, stream, future

Im trying to get data from database and transmit that data to screen using stream.
I done this using `FutureBuilder` that solution is working as spectated , but i need to use `streambuilder` 
Can anyone help me to find the issue.
I have a method that get data from database

```
Future<List<CementSandAggregateView>> getAllRatios() async{
   List<CementSandAggregateView> ratioList = new List();

    var types = await ratioRepository.getAll();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < types.length ; i ++){

      CementSandAggregateView view = new CementSandAggregateView();

      String cementRatio = types[i].cement.floor() < types[i].cement ? types[i].cement.toStringAsFixed(1):types[i].cement.toStringAsFixed(0);
      String sandRatio = types[i].sand.floor() < types[i].sand ? types[i].sand.toStringAsFixed(1):types[i].sand.toStringAsFixed(0);
      String aggregateRatio = types[i].aggregate.floor() < types[i].aggregate ? types[i].aggregate.toStringAsFixed(1):types[i].aggregate.toStringAsFixed(0);

      view.ratio = "$cementRatio:$sandRatio:$aggregateRatio (${types[i].name})";
      view.id = types[i].id;
      view.name = types[i].name;
      print(view.ratio);
      ratioList.add(view);
    }

    return ratioList;
  }
```

and i want to send this data using stream

```
class CementSandAggregateMixBloC {
    BehaviorSubject<Future<List<CementSandAggregateView>>> _cSAMixController;
    BLoCProvider provider;
  CementSandAggregateMixBloC(){
    provider = new BLoCProvider();
    _cSAMixController = new BehaviorSubject<Future<List<CementSandAggregateView>>>();

    _cSAMixController.add(provider.getAllRatios());
  }

  Observable<Future<List<CementSandAggregateView>>> inputObservable() => _cSAMixController.stream;

    void dispose() {
    _cSAMixController.close();
  }
}
```

in my screen i use stream using `streambuilder`

```
Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar1() {
    List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items = List();

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _rationBloC.inputObservable(),
      builder: (context,
          AsyncSnapshot<Future<List<CementSandAggregateView>>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            snapshot.data.then((onValue) => {
                  onValue.forEach((mix) => {})
                });

            return BottomNavigationBar(
                items: items,
                currentIndex: _selectedRatio,
                fixedColor: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
                onTap: _onItemTapped);
          } else {
            return new Center(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        } else {
          return new Container(width: 0.0,height: 0.0,);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

but data is not coming to screen

i have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293928/how-to-convert-a-future-in-flutter-to-a-stream) but no chance !

can anyone help me to convert future result in to stream ?

Thanks.

Comment: you need `BehaviorSubject<List<CementSandAggregateView>>`, not `BehaviorSubject<Future<List<CementSandAggregateView>>>` - the same applies to your `Stream`

Comment: ok. If  i use `BehaviorSubject<List<CementSandAggregateView>>` instead of `BehaviorSubject<Future<List<CementSandAggregateView>>>` the return type from the provider should be changed , isn't it?

Comment: not really: read [this](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures) - the second paragraph says how to deal with it: `"Asynchronous operations let your program complete other work while waiting for an operation to finish. Dart uses Future objects (futures) to represent the results of asynchronous operations. To work with futures, you can use either async and await or the Future API."`

Comment: The link is not working , thanks for the info . ill check it when content is available.

Comment: it is working: i double-checked it a second ago

Comment: oh , now it's working. thanks @pskink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach to achive this is `await` for the future complete and then put the data inside your stream.

In your bloc class:

```
void _init() async {
   List<CementSandAggregateView> data = await provider.getAllRatios();
   _cSAMixController.add(data);
}

CementSandAggregateMixBloC(){
    provider = new BLoCProvider();
    _cSAMixController = BehaviorSubject< List<CementSandAggregateView> >();
    _init();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `_init()` should be calld in `initState()` method of `StatefulWidget`, or use this code in `initState` or `build` method.

```
WidgetBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(() => _init());
```

This means call of the procedure just after 1st frame rendered, i.e. just after `build`.