# Flutter error: The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

This is the getUser function which returns studentsc which is a string, i read somewhere since im using async i should use future builder

```
getUser() async{
   print(widget.scourse);
    DocumentSnapshot dsa = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
             .collection("users")
             .doc("${widget.scourse}")
             .get();

    
    final studentsc=dsa.get('courseName').toString().toLowerCase().split(" ").join() +"student";

   return studentsc;
  }
```

> The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't
> be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'.

```
child: FutureBuilder(
                  future:     FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(getUser()).orderBy("num").snapshots(),
```

i can't find a work around for this please help

Comment: Try using `StreamBuilder` instead of `FutureBuilder`

Comment: I did but then for calling a firebase instance im using async and await

Comment: You are receiving a model class data?

Comment: no querying through email in db for the coursename

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/53293928/10157127

Comment: Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg.

Comment: as in this case use Stream.fromFuture() where ?

Comment: 1. collection() required String, your getUser() look like it was Future<String>
2. snapshot() will return Stream, you can't use it on FutureBuilder, use get() instead, but the cons is once the data updated, you need to update your state manually, so adjust your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i simply put a set state in `getUser()` which sets a variable's value equal to the value as studentsc and passed that value as collection name

also resorted to using `StreamBuilder`