# How to convert a Future to a Stream WHICH DOES NOT RETURN ANYTHING

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have this working code, which draws from firebase all the documents inside the sub-collection "Users". I am trying to convert it to Stream Builder, but the results are not pretty as I do not get any output at all, since this method does not return anything, it merely populates a list with all the document IDs (Which I use in other parts of the code)

I converted a Future Builder to a Stream Builder, hoping to change this method too, to read data realtime.

Here is the method

```
Future getDocIDs() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      //.orderBy('rank', descending: false)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
              print(document.reference.id);
              documentIDs.add(document.reference.id);
            })
          });
  documentIDs.sort();
  setState(() {});
}
```

My attempt to convert them to future were

```
Stream getDocIDs() async* {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Users')
      //.orderBy('rank', descending: false)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
              print(document.reference.id);
              documentIDs.add(document.reference.id);
            })
          });
  documentIDs.sort();
  setState(() {});
}
```

I even tried adding yield keyword before document IDs

Comment: I don't understand why you'd convert it from a Future (single) event to a Stream (many events, but you have only one).

Comment: Calling `setState` does not turn something into a stream. If you have a future, you can turn it into a stream with `Stream.fromFuture(theFuture)` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293928/how-to-convert-a-future-in-flutter-to-a-stream